# search page work on my pc and doesn't on net

Tags: asp.net

I have a search page with gridview for searching in books all things are good in my PC when i make search with any part of book title the result appear when i published the page on net the page doesn't return any result I'm sure there are books with the criteria I search for ?

Comment: Did you try running a trace (e.g SQL Server Profiler) on your database server to ensure that a query is actually being executed? If so, is it returning the right results? If you dont see a query, could be anything from a network credentials issue, config setting, etc...

Answer (score 0):

When you published, did you make sure your published version is pointing at the right database?